# How to use *args?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I'm writing a code that hopefully works similarly to scipy.integrate.solve_ivp. I'm supposed to allow for there to be extra parameters by using *args. Basically one of the functions I'm supposed to run is what I've defined in my code as f2a and I'm supposed to assign Vin,D,k as extra parameters. It won't let me assign all three of them. Also I was never given a value for k (don't know if that's important or if assigning it as *k takes care of it). I've put my entire code so far for this project below. F2a is at the top.

```
    import numpy as np
    import math

    tspan=np.array([0,20])
    #defining functions
    Vin=150 #m^3/min
    H0=7 #initial height, meters
    D=7 #diameter, m**2
    #they never told us what k is...k must be args thingy?
    def f2a(t,H,Vin,D,*k):
        Vin=150 #m^3/min
        D=7 #diameter, m**2
        #they never told us what k is...k must be args
        dhdt=4/(math.pi*D**2)*(Vin-k*np.sqrt(H))
        return(dhdt)

    x0=1 #initial cond.
    y0=1
    def fb2(J,t):
        x=J[0]
        y=J[1]
        dxdt=0.25*y-x
        dydt=3*x-y
        return([dxdt,dydt])


   
    #x0 and y0 are initial conditions

    def odeRK4(function,tspan,R,h,*args):
        #args allows for the possibility of extra parameters to be added?

        #R is vector of inital conditions
        x0=R[0]
        y0=R[1]


        #writing statement for what to do if h isnt given/other thing
        if h==None:
            h=.01*(tspan[1]-tspan[0])
        elif h> tspan[1]-tspan[0]:
            h=.01*(tspan[1]-tspan[0])
        else:
            h=h
        #defining the 2-element array (i hope)
        #pretty sure tspan is range of t values
        x0=tspan[0] #probably 0 if this is meant for time
        xn=tspan[1] #whatever time we want it to end at?
        #xn is final x value-t
        #x0 is initial

        def f(x,y):
            f= eval(function)
            return f
        #eval is used to evaluate whatever I put in the function place when I recall ode
        #this won't work without eval to run the functions

        t_values=np.arange(0,20,21)
        for i in t_values:
            #rk4 method
            k1=h*(f(x0,y0))
            k2=h*(f((x0+h/2), (y0+k1/2)))
            k3=h*(f((x0+h/2), (y0+k2/2)))
            k4=h*(f((x0+h), (y0+k3)))
    
            n=(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
            #new y value
            yn=y0+n
            #makes it so new y and x are used for next # in range
            y0=yn
            xn=x0+h
            print ('Y=')
            print(yn)
            print('When t=')
            print(xn)

    print('For 3A:')
    odeRK4("f2a(x,y,*k)", [0,20],[0,H0], None)
```

Comment: You can't guess things like this.  You aren't passing any "extra args" in your call to odfRK4, so `args` is going to be empty.  As it is, your `f2a` expects 4 arguments, and you are only passing 3.  Plus, you're passing x and y, and the arguements don't look like that.  You shouldn't be using `eval` like this anyway.  Where did you get this code?

Comment: Even if you removed `Vin` and `D` from the parameter list, `f2a` could read them from the outer function.

Comment: you might want to switch to using default values instead. If you know which optional arguments you're might get, it's an easier to read option, and likely more robust as well